# what is the difference between ng:click and ng-click?

Tags: angularjs

I can't find any documentation on ng:click.  My todo list application does not work unless I use ng:click as opposed to ng-click, yet I can't find any documentation on it.   Is it the same as ng-click?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the docs here: http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

> The normalization process is as follows:
>
> Strip x- and data- from the front of the element/attributes. Convert
>   the :, -, or _-delimited name to camelCase.

So, angular interprets all of these as `ngClick` and then runs the directive named `ngClick`.

```
<button ng:click="myFunc()">ng:click</button>
<button ng-click="myFunc()">ng-click</button>
<button ng_click="myFunc()">ng_click</button>
```

[See this live demo (click).](http://jsbin.com/arAkuZo/1/edit)

This being, your issue must be with your usage, which is not included. As this post is asking "What is the difference" and you have been answered that there is none, you might want to make a new post concerning the issue with your code and include your code.

#### Update based on your comment:

There are so many problem with your code that it would be unreasonable to go into depth about all of them. I'll give you some starting points for study.

First, here's a live demo of your code as it ought to look: http://jsbin.com/arAkuZo/6/edit

- The "br" tag is deprecated and should no longer be used. Use css for that.
- Your angular version is far out of date.
- Don't use the global syntax for angular. Make a module and add your controller, etc to it.
- There are several directives like `ngModel` that you seem to be unfamiliar with.
- camelCase is the accepted standard for variable naming and Angular emphasizes it, so make it a note to use camelCase always. (at least almost always).

Comment: For example, in my current code if I exchange a ng:click for an ng:click, or an ng:controller for a ng-controller, the app does not work.  http://jsbin.com/arAkuZo/3/edit

Comment: @user3056150 see my updated answer. That should be plenty to help you out, especially the live demo I linked.

Comment: Yes I'm quite new to all this, and you've been an incredible help to me!  One more question if you don't mind:  I am testing this app on a local server using node.js, but when I try to deploy the refactored code, I get the error, "error: no module: myapp". Here is my server.js file: http://jsbin.com/ONapaWim/1/edit.  Again, I truly do appreciate you helping me! :)

Comment: @user3056150 unfortunately, I can't help you there. I'm not familiar with node.js, nor do I understand why it would be involved with the issue. That error means that you have `ng-app="myApp"` in your html, but the angular framework can't find a module called "myApp" in your javascript code. In other words, this is the first error that will occur if the angular library is loaded, you have an app declared in your html, AND you don't have that app delcared in your javascript. So I guess your javascript isn't included. As you said my answer is helpful, could you mark it as the accepted answer?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they're the same thing. Read http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive and http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/ie.